# Concurrency handling while moving ImageView object

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency

I'm writing dining philosophers algorithm in JavaFX and I have a problem with thread synchronization while many threads are trying to move object simultaneously. Object should be movable only if it's in inital position.

Here is object class:

```
class ObjectToMove {
     ImageView imageView;
     boolean isAvailable;
     (...)

     synchronized public void moveToPosition(int positionNumber) {
         while(!isAvailable) {
             try {
                 wait();
             } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                 return;
             }
         }
         isAvailable = false;
         imageView.setX(positionsList.get(positionNumber).getXPosition());
         imageView.setY(positionsList.get(positionNumber).getYPosition());
     }

     synchronized public void backToInitalPosition() {
         imageView.setX(positionsList.get(initalPosition).getXPosition());
         imageView.setY(positionsList.get(initalPosition).getYPosition());
         isAvailable= true;
         notifyAll();
     }
}
```

Here is class where objects are moved:

```
class MovingClass implements Runnable {
    ObjectToMove objectToMove1;
    ObjectToMove objectToMove2;

    (...)

    public doSomeMoving() {
        objectToMove1.moveToPosition(positionNumber);
        objectToMove2.moveToPosition(otherPositionNumber);

        try() {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch(InterruptedException iex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        objectToMove1.backToInitalPosition();
        objectToMove2.backToInitalPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            doSomeMoving();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to synchronize threads? All threads have to wait for their turn until object is back to it's inital position.

Comment: do you know about wait/notify/notifyall api's? These are bets place to start with multithreading.

Comment: I did something like above but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note that, distinct from any threading issues, `ImageView.setX(..)` and `ImageView.setY(...)` probably don't do what you think. (They effectively give the coordinates of the viewport into the image.). You are probably looking for `setLayoutX(...)` and `setLayoutY(...)`. For the threading, I recommend acquainting yourself with the higher level APIs of the [`java.util.concurrent` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Low-level synchronization, `wait()` and `notify()` have no place in application code imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study this [reference solution](http://everythingcomputerscience.com/projects/java_programs/DiningPhilosophers.txt) for the dining philosopher's problem using [java.util.concurrent.locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html).  Sorry it's just a link, but I don't know about the copyright for copy and pasting it into StackOverflow.

The solution is based upon [high level concurrency Lock objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html), which I would recommend as often a more appropriate abstraction for concurrent code than low level [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), wait and notify mechanisms.

Some potential modifications you may wish to make to the sample solution:

- Use [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)
- with [a fixed thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-)
- and a [ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html)
- utilizing [daemon threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-)
- Replace `System.out` calls with `Platform.runLater` invocations to update your JavaFX UI.

JavaFX application code that modifies the active scene graph must be single threaded and all such modifications performed on the JavaFX application thread.  As you are running different threads, you must surround any blocks modifying the scene graph (e.g. image positions) with [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) calls, so that those blocks of code are scheduled to run later on the JavaFX application thread.

As a development approach, I would recommend that you write your program to draw the basic UI and any [animations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm) you wish for it and ensure that works OK without spawning new threads, before integrating the concurrent dining philosophers algorithm into it.

Comment: My algorithm was working fine without GUI. Major problem was displaying elements without `Platform.runLater`. After adding that in 2 places everything is working great. Thanks a lot for help!